# How to eliminate escape slashed inserted by prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-injection

My application currently applies `if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) { stripslashes }` followed by `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to all strings, confirms email and URL formats with filters and confirms all integer and image data types before using them in a query.

I've mastered the basics of applying prepared statements with parameters, e.g.,

```
$query = "INSERT INTO my_table (col1, col2, modified) VALUES (?,?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $string1, $string2);

if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {display error}
else {do something else}
```

When a string has an apostrophe (single quote), as in `O'Grady`, it is escaped with a backslash as `O\'Grady` when inserted. And every time a user updates the account the escape slashes increase exponentially. Is there a way to avoid this on INSERT and UPDATE; if not how can it be eliminated on SELECT so it doesn't display when retrieved (and multiply)?

Comment: Don't escape values used in prepared statements, otherwise you're double escaping them (because that's what binding does for you)

Comment: In other words: remove the `mysqli_real_escape_string()` calls from your code.

Comment: I tried that; it doesn't make any difference. I think it is a function of the prepared statement to add the escape because of the single quote. The question is how to deal with it.

Comment: Well, you're wrong. It's a function of your code. **Remove it**

Comment: My humble apologies. I thought I had removed it but hadn't. Problem solved.